# How to get a multiple pagination api in a python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, pagination

I learn python and I want to use api.
I make small programs to get information, and I block on my next program.
I want to make a program for scraping all students on my school api.
The problem is the limit pagination, I get 15 users, but not all.

I search on documentation how use.
I try to get the information with a loop "for" and the specific api parameters :

> The Link HTTP response header contains pagination data with first,
> previous, next and last raw pages links when available, under the
> format
>
> link: [http://xxx.intra.xxx.fr/v2/{Resource}?page=X+1](http://xxx.intra.xxx.fr/v2/%7BResource%7D?page=X+1); rel="next",
> [http://xxx.intra.xxx.fr/v2/{Resource}?page=X-1](http://xxx.intra.xxx.fr/v2/%7BResource%7D?page=X-1); rel="prev",
> [http://xxx.intra.xxx.fr/v2/{Resource}?page=1](http://xxx.intra.xxx.fr/v2/%7BResource%7D?page=1); rel="first",
> [http://xxx.intra.xxx.fr/v2/{Resource}?page=X+n](http://xxx.intra.xxx.fr/v2/%7BResource%7D?page=X+n); rel="last"

Problem, I don't know to to scrape all information in all pages, not only on the first page.
My program code :

```
import requests
import json
import sys
from sys import argv
from operator import itemgetter, attrgetter
import json  
import os


UID = 'REDACTED_USER_ID'
SECRET = 'REDACTED_SECRET_KEY'

class CONST(object):
   try:
      campus = sys.argv[1]
      month = sys.argv[2]
      year = sys.argv[3]
  except:
     print("Error : aucun argument")
     print('Usage: "campus_id" (EX:1) "month" (july) "year" (2016)')
     exit()

  d = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials', 'client_id': UID, 'client_secret': SECRET}
  r = requests.post("https://api.intra.xxx.fr/oauth/token", data=d)
  token = r.json()['access_token']
  print(token)
  h = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}
  get_students = requests.get('https://api.intra.xxx.fr/v2/cursus/1/users?filter[primary_campus_id]=' + campus + '&filter[pool_month]=' + month + '&filter[pool_year]=' + year + '&sort=login', headers=h)

def __setattr__(self, *_):
    pass

CONST = CONST()

def campus_id(CAMPUS, MONTH, YEAR, *args):
    campus = CAMPUS
    if str.isnumeric(campus):
        return(campus)
    else:
        print("Error : campus_id requiert un chiffre")
        print('Usage: "campus_id" (EX:1) "month" (july) "year" (2016)')
        exit()

def pool_month(CAMPUS, MONTH, YEAR, *args):
    month = MONTH
    if str.isalpha(month):
        return(month)
    else:
        print("Error : pool_month requiert un mois en lettre")
        print('Usage: "campus_id" (EX:1) "month" (july) "year" (2016)')
        exit()

def pool_year(CAMPUS, MONTH, YEAR, *args):
    year = YEAR
    if str.isnumeric(year):
        return(year)
    else:
        print("Error : pool_year requiert au moins un chiffre")
        print('Usage: "campus_id" (EX:1) "month" (july) "year" (2016)')
        exit()

def get_infos(CAMPUS, MONTH, YEAR, *args):
    if len(argv) != 4:
        print('Wrongs arguments !')
        print('Usage: "campus_id" (EX:1) "month" (july) "year" (2016)')
        exit()

    campus = campus_id(*argv[1:], *argv[2:], *argv[3:])
    month = pool_month(*argv[1:], *argv[2:], *argv[3:])
    year = pool_year(*argv[1:], *argv[2:], *argv[3:])
    get_level = CONST.get_students
#  print(json.dumps(get_level.json(),indent=4))
    level = get_level.json()
    tab = []
    for item in level:
        tab.append(item['login'])
    chain = ' \n'.join(tab)
    fichier = open("test.out", "w")
    fichier = open("test.out", "a")
    fichier.write(chain + "\n")
    fichier.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = get_infos(*argv[1:], *argv[2:], *argv[3:])
    print(test)
```

the code :

```
for item in level:
    tab.append(item['login'])
```

is my array list with the logins I found (ex : for moment I've "a" "b" "c" "d"), and I want to get all users

console example :

```
> api-test python3 api-test3.py "1" "september" "2017"
> api-test 
> cat test.out
aaiche
abaille
abezanni
abouquet
acourtin
adfourca
adpusel
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `requests.get` function, you should [pass the query parameters](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) in the `params` keyword argument.

So you would want something like

```
# ... earlier stuff
h = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}
params = {
    'filter[primary_campus_id]': campus,
    'filter[pool_month]': month,
    'filter[pool_year]': year,
    'sort': 'login'
}
get_students = requests.get('https://api.intra.xxx.fr/v2/cursus/1/users', params=params, headers=h)

# and so on ...
```

To answer your pagination question in particular, you want to add an additional `page` parameter to the `params` dictionary. So you could add a loop

```
params = { ... }  # as before
for page_idx in range(number_of_pages):
    params['page'] = page_idx
    get_students_page = requests.get(...)
    # combine the outputs somehow, but that depends on the response
# and so on...
```

Comment: Hello Andrew, thx for your fast answer !
You alright for the query params, thanks to you is cleaner.

For the pagination, no, i dont want a "page" parameter.
Actually with my script ive all page 1 users.
I want to get page 1 users + other users pages with the "first, previous, next and last" options."

Comment: The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26980639/api-capture-all-paginated-data-python) has some useful details about automating through the "rel=next" tags, though the actual implementation depends on the details of the response format.